# Full bounty incorrectly awarded

Tags: bug, bounties, accepted-answer, expired-bounty

Related: [Debate about the correct answer (large bounty involved)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/224068/debate-about-the-correct-answer-large-bounty-involved)

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21921790/best-approach-to-real-time-http-streaming-to-html5-video-client) had a [bounty added](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/21921790/revisions) by someone who is not the question owner.

> asked Feb 20 at 23:13
>   deandob
>
> Bounty Started worth 500 reputation by jwriteclub
>   occurred Feb 23 at 5:30

It was automatically awarded

> Bounty Ended with szatmary's answer chosen by Community♦
>   occurred yesterday

The answer received the full 500 points

> This answer has been awarded bounties worth 500 reputation by Community

From the [bounty help page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/bounty):

> If you do not award your bounty within 7 days (plus the grace period), the highest voted answer created after the bounty started with a minimum score of 2 will be awarded half the bounty amount. If there's no answer meeting those criteria, the bounty is not awarded to anyone.
>
> **If the bounty was started by the question owner**, and the question owner accepts an answer posted during the bounty period, and the bounty expires without an explicit award then we assume the bounty owner liked the answer they accepted and award it the full bounty amount at the time of bounty expiration.

Am I missing something or should this answer only have received half the bounty?

Comment: The answer was accepted, albeit in the grace period.

Comment: @LowerClassOverflowian: Then the person offering the bounty should have awarded it manually. Them's the rules, an accepted answer (if posted during the bounty period) is automatically awarded the full bounty.

Comment: @LowerClassOverflowian: Yes. But I think you may not actually get any points.. Not sure on that part.

Comment: @LowerClassOverflowian: actually, reading the [bounty faq](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16065/how-does-the-bounty-system-work) implies that this is indeed a bug: *If the **bounty starter** accepted an answer during the bounty period*; this is not the case here.

Comment: @MartijnPieters It's also on the help page in the piece I quoted, I'll add emphasis to that part.

Comment: I had encountered an exactly similar scenario [on this question of mine](http://askubuntu.com/questions/229274/problem-resolving-many-of-the-web-pages) where someone else started the bounty, I accepted the answer before bounty period ended and the answer was awarded the complete bounty amount.

Answer (score 2):

This is indeed a confusing scenario. Here's some pics to hopefully show the relevant info.

https://stackoverflow.com/users/210785/szatmary?tab=reputation
[image]
https://stackoverflow.com/posts/21921790/revisions
[image]
[image]

Based on the information, I think that IF the person that asked the question, would have had to accept the answer before 5:30 Sunday. Which they didn't do. They accepted it at 10:22 Sunday.

Unless, the grace period is somehow included in the accepting an answer, then he did accept an answer within that time, since the grace period adds a day.

**But that is irrelevant since the person who asked the question did not start the bounty.**

So yes, this person should have only been rewarded 250 instead of 500.

Comment: All this information should be irrelevant. The text states that acceptance should only cause a full bounty award if the bounty was **started by the owner of the question**, which is not true in this case. If it were, there would be nothing wrong here. The bounty grace period is included in the accepting timeline.